# Can I Link My Bethesda.net ESL and Steam ESL?

Tags: steam, the-elder-scrolls-legends

I already have been playing Elder Scrolls Legends on Betheda.net, and have earned some good cards and titles. The game just recently became available on Steam and I'm wondering if there is any way I can join my existing account to my new steam one, so I don't have to re-earn all those cards and titles. I would really prefer to avoid the add a "Non-Steam Game..." approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that my Steam account automatically synced with my Bethesda.net account. All I had to do was download it from Steam and all of my cards were already there. Turns out there was nothing to fix!